# awk: print certain columns and a series of concsecutive columns

Tags: awk

If I want to print, say, the fourth column till the tenth column, I can use:

```
awk '{for( i=4; i<=10; i++ ){printf( "%s ", $i )}; printf( "\n"); }
```

But what if I want to print columns 1, 3, and then 4-10, and then 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '{printf("%s %s",$1,$3);for( i=4; i<=10; i++ ){printf( "%s ", $i )}; printf(" %s\n",$12);}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=12;i++) if(i!~/^(2|11)$/) printf "%s ",$i; print "" }' file
```

- `if(i!~/^(2|11)$/)` - ensures that it's not the 2nd or the 11th field. You can extend the alternation group `(2|11|...)` to multiple field numbers that should be skipped